# Update /.aws/config file on your local machine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-config

I am trying to update the local aws/config file on my mac. I am not able to read or update any contents of the config file.

```
import configparser
import os
creds_dir = os.path.dirname("~/.aws/config")
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()

if not config.has_section("some"):
    config.add_section("some")

# METHOD -1
config.set("some", 'aws_access_key_id', "access_key")
config.set("some", 'aws_secret_access_key', "secret_key")
config.set("some", 'aws_session_token', "token")
config.set("some", 'aws_security_token', "token")
config.write("~/.aws/config")


# METHOD -2
with open('~/.aws/credentials', 'a') as file_out:
    file_out.write("[profile]")
    file_out.write("aws_access_key_id = aaa")
    file_out.write("aws_secret_access_key = bbb")
    file_out.write("aws_session_token = cccc")
```

I am getting an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.aws/credentials'
```

I could open the file from my mac terminal and view it.

Comment: Your application doesn't take advantage of the shell's expansion of tilde. [Expand](https://nickymarino.com/2018/12/17/expand-tilde-paths/) `~` to the full name of your home folder.

Comment: Do you have aws cli? Can you please try to run `aws help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to be:

```
creds_file = os.path.expanduser("~/.aws/config")
```

or

```
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.aws/config"), 'a') as file_out:
```

The `~` expansion is part of the shell normally and so you need to expand it.  `expanduser` returns a string that has the full path name to the file.